# How to learn to web scrape/Selenium?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I recently learned how to build ML models using sci-kit learn, tensorflow and keras and I applied my learnings to create a model to predict NBA games. My model ended up doing pretty well, so much so that I'd like to create a self-updating database that scrapes basketball-reference.com/leagues/ regularly to update game data so that anytime I want a prediction for an upcoming NBA game I can have the parameters ready without needing to do anything.

For this to work I need to know how to scrape basketball-reference.com/leagues/ and I thought I might try to use Selenium but it turned out to be more difficult than I realized. Most of my knowledge with programming/compsci is self-taught so I'm not sure where to turn or what to do to learn how to use Selenium.

Does anyone have any resources they may suggest or maybe some 'pre-requisites' that I should know before I try using Selenium?

I was thinking about checking out a course on Udemy!

Comment: Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more

Comment: In your case you may even not require Selenium to achieve what you want. 
A get requests (with **requests library**) combined with **Beautifulsoup** will do the trick: 
`import requests #pip install requests
from bs4 import Beautifulsoup #pip install bs4

r = requests.get(‘https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/’)
soup = Beautifulsoup(r.text, ‘lxml’) #pip install lxml
` 
As far as I can see this website has a lot of tables, most of your work will be to identify the elements you need. So you should take a look at those libraries there are plenty of tutorials. Hope this helps you:)